# set weight programatically on listview adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-adapter

I have tried to make a dynamic listview adapter for my data, I don't know exactly how many items I will have so I make a loop creating textviews and adding them to an horizontal linearlayout, everything works, except the size, it seems there is no way to know the list width from within the adapter so I tried to set the layoutparams of the textviews to work with weight, but either it does nothing or everything dissapears.

adapter getView:

```
LinearLayout m = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_lo);
String[] s = filtered[position];
for(String i:s)
    {
        TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f);
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setText(i);
        m.addView(tv,params);
    }
```

this creates all the textviews but they are all just drawed one after another.
I have tried with the LinearLayout.LayoutParams but it's the same.
Any other ideas I might try?

Answer (score 0):

in the first write custom adapter the get the layout parameter
and then calculate the height:

```
AccountCustomAdapter Adt = new AccountCustomAdapter(this,account);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = accountLV.getLayoutParams();

params.width = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
params.height = Adt.getGroupCount() * 70;
```

Comment: what is an AccountCustomAdapter? and why is it used only for height?

Comment: its an adapter used to fill data in the list.